# Undefined variable PDO

Tags: php, pdo, phpstorm

I use PDO for the database connection. All the PDO stuff has been initialized in a file application_top.php.

```
if(!isset($db)) {
  $db = new Morrow\Db(array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => DB_SERVER,
    'db'       => DB_DATABASE,
    'user'     => DB_SERVER_USERNAME,
    'pass'     => DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    'encoding' => '"utf8"',
  ));
}
```

This works fine. But PHPStorm gives me a warning

> Undefined variable 'db'

The code looks like

```
require_once 'includes/application_top.php';
...
$pass = $db->result_one("
  SELECT customers_password
  FROM   " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . "
  WHERE  customers_id = " . (int)$_SESSION['customer_id']
);
```

But why is $db undefined?

Comment: you really should stop using *include oriented programming* as your approach for development

Comment: includes/application_top.php is not found for the second code file that uses it.

Comment: all the other vars or constants which are initialized in application_top.php are known in the second code file

Comment: My bad diagnostics. So Morrow\Db() is undefined? use Morrow\Db; You should enable PHP error echoes.

Comment: Your `$db` variable is 1) declared in include file and 2) declared inside conditional statement. Since PhpStorm does not actually execute your code, it cannot guarantee that this variable will be available elsewhere and if it will be declared at all. In this particular case try declaring it globally via PHPDoc comment (try placing it in `application_top.php` before the `if(!isset($db))` line: **`/** @var \Morrow\Db $db Optional description */`**

Comment: If the above will not work (sorry, cannot test your setup -- do not have your files) then try creating some .php file (e.g. `_ide_helper.php`) and place it anywhere in your project (will be used by IDE ONLY). Then place your global variable definitions there (once again -- will be used by IDE only). Something like this (2 lines): `/** @var \Morrow\Db $db Optional description */` `global $db;`.

Comment: That also doesn't work. I also removed the if(!isset($db)) for testing and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Well .. without reproducible SIMPLE project (few files, nothing biggie) I personally cannot help further. I just know that this approach works perfectly fine in WordPress sites (which has quite different setup to yours). If you can provide some simple sample project (better do it on your JB forum thread) then I may have a look -- not a prob at all.

Comment: LazyOne, would you give me your emailaddress? I could send you some project files

Comment: Replied you via email. In case you have not received it: the best and easiest option would be to disable that part of the inspection: `"Settings | Inspections | PHP | Undefined | Undefined variable"` -- uncheck **"Enable inspection in global scope"** option.

Answer (score -1):

I do like this:

```
require_once 'includes/application_top.php';
...
if (!isset($db)) exit; // or die, return false, thrown exception

$pass = $db->result_one("
  SELECT customers_password
  FROM   " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . "
  WHERE  customers_id = " . (int)$_SESSION['customer_id']
);
```

It`s make PHPStorm happy and maybe gives me some point in security.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Either $db has been successfully created  in includes/application_top.php, and in this case this condition will never be evaluated to true, or, in case it failed, an exception will be thrown, and the code execution simply will never reach this condition at all.