# Use variable from "require()" function in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

So, my problem isn't really a problem because the code is working even tho **[phpstorm](/questions/tagged/phpstorm)** doesn't seem to be happy with what I do.

I'm working on a local project for a session based website and I'm using a database, in fact I use **[pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo)** to connect to mysql in a isolated file, like so :

***db.php***

```php
<?php 
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=MyIPAddress;dbname=MyDB', 'user', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: ". $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

And when I need to use and do something with the DB I do like this  :

***connection.php***

```php
<?php
session_start();
require('./scripts/db.php');

$sql = "query";
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':variable', variable);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error coming from the database : " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The funny part that took me here is that PhpStorm is red-underlining `$db` in the `try-catch` clause with the following message `Undefined variable '$db'`.

But still works, I'm just curious of why this happens. If there is a 'better' or 'cleaner' way to do this. Or if it's just a message that should go to the developers of PhpStorm at JetBrains...

Thanks for your shared knowledge !

PhpStorm told me to define a global variable `$db` which didn't change anything. Other than that I don't know what to do...

Comment: oh can you try adding a PHPDoc comment in your db.php which can provide a hint to the IDE `/** @var PDO $db */` something like this. I believe it's something to do with static code analysis of IDE's

Comment: hope this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476778/phpstorm-undefined-variables-caused-by-include-require)

Comment: I strongly recommend coding this differently. Yes it may work but it makes code unreadable. It would be preferable to do something like `return $db;` in your `db.php` and then do `$db = require('./db.php');`